# DataMatrix Barcode in Java Script

Tags: javascript, barcode, datamatrix

How to generate DataMatrix barcode in JavaScript only JavaScript or any other Library in Javascript free

I have an Image and I want to put an generated DataMatrix barcode in this image
based on any given Value I tried Jsbarcode Library but It doesn't support DataMatrix barcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the author of [bwip-js](https://bwip-js.metafloor.com/), I am partial to that javascript library.  It implements several different datamatrix standards in addition to many other symbologies.  Generating a datamatrix symbol is as easy as:

```
import { datamatrix } from 'bwip-js';

try {
    datamatrix('my-canvas', options);
} catch (e) {
    // handle error
}
```

That example is for the browser (drawing to a canvas object).  The node-js version generates a PNG image in a Buffer.

Comment: Hi and Good Morning I just want to use pure Javascript or any other CDN just